# Cannot access an attribute within a JSON object

Tags: javascript, node.js

1. I created a record object that contains a series of attributes (var record = {...})
2. console.log(record) gives me:

`{ 'Label': 'Test Location 3',
  'Doshii Location ID': '123',
  'Zip API Key': 'LBUcHlihsel7JkiCuPykiRuQ1+upbiEZuRFYU/cI/VZ7e0u0ldSkJlcD/NvTUZJCkMznQ8Wk4/qPfzfyfopzQcATzkde3H/0EQbwfJ3qWY5GZj8aK2yUNPGP+rLZA3BeQOQhu4iJuZsVdno/prfG7419x78v5P1fwY8AMC6u6nSUW69bjD5dplMqdH7fQ+1gWlN0UIpMzJeY7TugELofk85DdQHxtu7/oeKiSdJ0Qs6Z/FprWEqcyUgKVHwsUBcGyIYzrGZx4Yt/GjanlhYhibPtmHyMQUseZ7x5TJodSlDxjHR8pSa6+MXLQ9xRs8Hn6COr7vVnIGMJtMkkNxmJ/g==',
  'Zip Location ID': '123' }`

3. `console.log(JSON.stringify(record));` 
   gives me:

`{"Label":"Test Location 3","Doshii Location ID":"123","Zip API Key":"LBUcHlihsel7JkiCuPykiRuQ1+upbiEZuRFYU/cI/VZ7e0u0ldSkJlcD/NvTUZJCkMznQ8Wk4/qPfzfyfopzQcATzkde3H/0EQbwfJ3qWY5GZj8aK2yUNPGP+rLZA3BeQOQhu4iJuZsVdno/prfG7419x78v5P1fwY8AMC6u6nSUW69bjD5dplMqdH7fQ+1gWlN0UIpMzJeY7TugELofk85DdQHxtu7/oeKiSdJ0Qs6Z/FprWEqcyUgKVHwsUBcGyIYzrGZx4Yt/GjanlhYhibPtmHyMQUseZ7x5TJodSlDxjHR8pSa6+MXLQ9xRs8Hn6COr7vVnIGMJtMkkNxmJ/g==","Zip Location ID":"123"}`

4. `var label = record["Label"]`;
5. `var newLocationObj = {
    doshiiLocationId: record["Doshii Location ID"],
    label: label,
    zipApiKey: record["Zip API Key"],
    zipLocationId: record["Zip Location ID"],
    ownerUserKey: req.body.ownerUserKey,
    createdByUserKey: tokenResult.userKey,
    createdDate: currentDate,
    lastModifiedDate: currentDate
   };`
6. `console.log("new location object - ",newLocationObj);`
7. Output is:

   new location object -  `{ doshiiLocationId: '123',
   label: undefined,
   zipApiKey: 'YlBEMw3YfX7uHiD8N8fjBI/Vq1IDVyjJhd1tN/gHrzIXLQ2iokJhfdx4Xuk8ovn4cFE6ftnxtDK/9WKKhEWtSVJgbBLBDhivLTe6k2y8S4e5x9QP2EQIIOM/psU+CL0ECO6S+UV859KOybI7MQZ4R+3wpTXeRn/k7uHX//Nnto/kqICTzh8ua4gkKRxdG2BnlvU0A54GzC+MTAWvRSAmjHMOupT3PrIEv/vMnpdVqFMNk8e0Ks+o6TOsYS/NEue5OKYRkPhZwhrgJj12Tz5Mphi8+XJcGSRw1X5unTmpG5q6FUF/ekv3Xig4KAvrOPJWImPSZqvIU0V4rG7Y9H+uNw==',
   zipLocationId: '123',
   ownerUserKey: 'a791154f-c978-4c4d-8721-d3ee4e910fdf',
   createdByUserKey: 'a791154f-c978-4c4d-8721-d3ee4e910fdf',
   createdDate: '2019-04-03T09:53:57.724Z',
   lastModifiedDate: '2019-04-03T09:53:57.724Z' }`

I cannot for the life of me figure out why label is undefined... Any ideas?

Comment: `Label` has a U+FEFF([Zero Width No-Break Space](https://unicode-table.com/en/FEFF/)) character before it https://jsfiddle.net/adigas/3mac6qbr/

Comment: You can try to debug this and do `console.log(Object.keys(record));` to get an array of keys that you can use to access properties values. Also, check if there are no any *invisible* characters in the `Label` key

Comment: Oh and **please** format your code in the post because now it's a disaster :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Label` key contains the following character before it `\ufeff` ([Zero Width No-Break Space, Byte Order Mark or BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)).

The right key to use is thus `\ufeffLabel` and not `Label`, which will return `undefined`:

```
const label = record['\ufeffLabel'];
```

Answer (score 1):

As jo_va said there is '\ufeff'(character) with your label key so either remove it or just stringify the object and parse it to remove that problem.
[image]